# Insert Thread ID in the Email Subject option not visible on Email-to-Case

Tags: email, apex-email-service, email2case

Not able to see some of the options like "Insert Thread ID in the Email Subject" and "Insert Thread ID in the Email Body" on Email-to-case settings in my sandbox.

PFA screenshot

[image]

How to enable this? can someone please help. following is the screenshot of my dev sandbox where options are available:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see there is a new default for any org created after Winter'21 (which is the release being deployed by Salesforce).

Long story short: I think you cannot change it, if your org is already at Winter'21 release. Check the [Email-to-Case documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_email_to_case_settings.htm&type=5) for more info:

> Insert Thread ID in the Email Subject
>
> NOTE Any org created after the Winter '21 release defaults to a new
> threading behavior. Until then, agents of existing orgs can update
> email templates at their convenience. Any email templates still using
> thread ID after the release return an empty string.

Plus the related release note: [Enhance Security with a New Threading Behavior for Email-To-Case](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_email_to_case.htm)